# C if statement failing to detect new line

Tags: c, return, newline

I'm working in PPM format magic number P3
http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

I have a really long unsigned char that is fall of chars spaces and newlines. When I print it out it nicely prints like this for example...

```
01 30 03 19 02 39 01 91 39 81 45 92 40 29 10 93
02 91 29 04 19 02 19 04 19 03 94 10 92 03 01 19 02
10 02 93 04
```

etc..
You see that some lines are longer then others.  This giant string was read in from a file and placed into an unsigned char *.  My problem is, when I go to change values, say change every 2nd char such as...

```
01 becomes 00   //changing the LSB 
30 becomes 31
```

I run into an issue when doing this.  The issue arrises when I reach the end of the line.  My if statement is not detecting the end of line token and so when it goes to grab the next value its not grabbing the 2nd number, but instead it grabs the first.

My if statement to detect the end of line is not working...

```
if(num[count] == '\n' || num[count] == '\0' || num[count] == '\r' || num[count]== '\t')
{
     count = count + 2;
}
```

The goal of this if statement is to detect the new line and progress count by 2, so the next value I fiddle with would be the 2 from 02 on the next line.  I'm not exactly sure why I can't detect the end of line token because surely something is there if when I print out the unsigned char * it prints in the above fashion with new lines.

Comment: Your newlines use 2 bytes.

Comment: so I should detect '\' ?

Comment: No, you need to detect a LF directly following a CR.

Comment: if a CR is \ or a hex number 0x0D how do I detect the LF behind it when it can be 0x0A which could be a char value?

Comment: You advance one character and then check.

Comment: It doesn't let me check for '\' and I get a multi character constant warning if I check for num[count] == '0x0D' && num[count+1] == '0x0A'

Comment: Well... yeah. You'd check for `0x0D` and `0x0A`, since those are characters. `'0x0D'` and `'0x0A'` are not.

Comment: I removed the ticks but its still not detecting the new line.

Comment: EOL is either one byte `'\n'`  or two byte `"\r\n"`. \ itself is escape, so you cannot check it by itself.

Comment: so I cannot check for a \n\r ?

Comment: But if you get to `'\r'` and `count+=2` it should work...

Comment: You should not `count += 2` on `'\n'` though. You skip the first on the next line that way.

Comment: my current if statement is checking for '\r' but not finding anything.  Assuming num[count] is at the newline, adding count += 2 would progress it the 2nd char on the next line - which is where I want it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111102/discussion-between-fridsun-and-user3622460).

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `num` has type `unsigned char *`, then each increment by one in your `count` variable corresponds to an increment by one octet (i.e. one byte). One octet corresponds to two hexadecimal values. Therefore, the `01` you have at the beginning of your input represents one octet. The `0` represents the four most significant bits, and the `1` represents the four least significant bits.

Therefore, when you increment count by two, which I'm assuming you're doing outside of that if statement as well, you're actually skipping over every other character.

As explained above, the misconception is that each of the hexadecimal values you see printed out corresponds, not to a byte, but to 4 bits within a byte. You describe the process you want to perform as "changing the LSB". But the example you gave is actually changing the least signifiant four bits, not the least significant byte.